# Помогите понять алгоритм работы автоинкремента(autoincrement operator), применительно к строкам

Tags: perl

Приведу пример. Допустим, есть код:

```
$a = "A9"; print ++$a, "\n";
$a = "bz"; print ++$a, "\n";
$a = "Zz"; print ++$a, "\n";
$a = "z9"; print ++$a, "\n";
$a = "9z"; print ++$a, "\n";
```

Почему вывод будет таким:

```
B0
ca
AAa
aa0
10
```

А не таким:

```
B0
ca
Aa
a0
0a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если переменная использовалась только в строковом контексте, имела значение, и не явлалась пустой строкой, и соответствовала шаблону:

**/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*$/**

то автоинкремент будет выполняться в пределах своего диапазона с добавлением символа (с переносом):